# Copy memory from char* to a location in larger char*

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to create code that places half a dozen variables into a `char*` and they are almost all multi-byte variables. Since they are all going into the same char* I'd like to be able to copy the data into the char* as easily as possible.

If there is no "standard" way for me to do this, I can easily make an inline function that deals with this for me. I was, however, hoping there would be a simple way of doing this, perhaps like:

`memcpy(char* target, char* source, int target_start_position, int source_length)`

So to elaborate on that:
I'd be copying all the data from source, into target. I'd copy the data to `target[target_start_position]` Then `source_length` would merely be for the function to know how much data it is going to be reading from the source.

---

What I actually tried. Perhaps you can see what my thought process was however.

=================

This is as simple as I was hoping to get things:
*(Which I realize doesn't work because I am assigning pointers as values)*

```
char* data;
unsigned __int64 pos = 0;

int string_len = sName.size();
unsigned __int64 data_size = sizeof(string_len) + string_len + (sizeof(int) * 10) + 3;
data = new char[data_size];

data[pos] = (char const*)(&string_len);
pos += sizeof(string_len);

data[pos] = (char const*)(&sName);
pos += string_len;

data[pos] = (char const*)(&iStatPoints);
pos += sizeof(int);
```

Note: I apologize for the title, that was the most precise way of describing the issue I could think of.

Comment: `int string_len = sizeof(sName);` You're taking the size of a pointer, not the length of a string.  This is why `strnlen` exists.  And, since this is C++, you have even better options. I would also prefer `std::array` and the like (string, etc)

Comment: @EdS. Thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to use std::string::size() / Edit made

Comment: Why aren't you assembling this all into a `std::string`, and then at the very end, if you need a C-style string, copy it out of the `std::string` you've assembled (ie. `strcpy(dest, s.c_str()`, where `s` is the `std::string` you just assembled?)

Comment: This also looks very suspect; `data[pos] = (char const*)(&string_len);`.  You're taking the address of a local variable.

Comment: @EdS. I am aware, there is a note directly above that code. I am fully aware that code will never function as I had intended when I wrote it. I understand why as well.

Comment: Ok... it's just hard to know what you're trying to do when your example has weird stuff in it

Comment: @JoeZ That sounds like a possible answer Joe, if you'd care to post it as one. I think I see what you're getting at though. Not sure how to do it however.

Comment: You changed the question to use `sName.size();`, but are still doing C-style ASCIIZ string operations in general.  You can just throw this all away and use `std::string` or `std::wstring`.  You should probably start by reading a tutorial, say http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html

Comment: @TonyD I appreciate your concern, but I can assure you I know how to treat strings. This may not function as expected, but its intended as a learning experience. I've already gone through and regurgitated other peoples' code that converts strings to `char*` so that I could save one to a file.. Now I am trying my own approach to see if it will work. However I am faced with a particular problem that I need help with before I can see if my endeavour will work. So again thanks, but I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the desired affect with pointer arithmetic. For example your desired function could be implemented as follows:

```
void *memcpy2(void *dest, const void *src, size_t offset, size_t length) {
  return memcpy((char*)dest + offset, src, length);
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow so I could simply use memcpy directly as its implemented in c++. Unless there is a simpler solution I will more than likely do this, thank you.